# How to fix a problem with a broken clang: missing stdlib.h

Tags: xcode, macos, clang

I have a problem with MacOS Mojave 10.14.5 and with the Xcode compiler. Precisely, I'm trying to install a package in R via Github and the compiler is complaning for a missing stdlib.h. Here is the error:

Can please someone explain me how to fix this problem?

```
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c bspline.c -o bspline.o
clang: warning: no such sysroot directory: '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk' [-Wmissing-sysroot]
In file included from bspline.c:3:
In file included from ./pomp_internal.h:6:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/R.h:55:11: fatal error: 'stdlib.h' file not found
# include <stdlib.h> /* Not used by R itself, but widely assumed in packages */
          ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [bspline.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘pomp’
* removing ‘/Users/Atorneri/Library/R/3.6/library/pomp’
* restoring previous ‘/Users/Atorneri/Library/R/3.6/library/pomp’
Error: Failed to install 'pomp' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘/var/folders/w7/v79h1vtd38579k18skjw2w280000gn/T//RtmpDSox3s/file3547ba46d4e/pomp_2.2.0.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: The important part of the message is `clang: warning: no such sysroot directory: '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk' [-Wmissing-sysroot]`. Where does the build-option `-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk` come from?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for pointing that out. I'm sorry, but I am not such an expert, and I do not get your question...

Answer (score 13):

Running in Terminal `xcode-select --install` solved the problem for me.

Comment: Worked instantly for me! Thank you.

Comment: It is simple and works for macOS Big Sur 11.6.5. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 7):

I fixed this issue for a colleague by creating a symlink.

Here is my file system:

```
pi@piPro18 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs
> ls -la
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  5 root  wheel  160 21 Sep 14:05 .
drwxr-xr-x  6 root  wheel  192 11 Sep 12:47 ..
drwxr-xr-x  4 root  wheel  128 30 Aug 07:47 DriverKit19.0.sdk
drwxr-xr-x  8 root  wheel  256 30 Aug 07:47 MacOSX.sdk
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 21 Sep 14:02 MacOSX10.14.sdk -> MacOSX.sdk
```

He was missing that symlink. So we created it:

`sudo ln -s MacOSX.sdk MacOSX10.14.sdk`

From https://github.com/mapnik/python-mapnik/issues/167

> Recently(?), Apple decided to stop naming their SDKs with versions but rather name them MacOSX.sdk and include an alias with the version name for compatibility

The one remaining mystery to me is why I have the symlink but my colleague doesn't.  If anyone can explain this one, please leave a comment.

Comment: Worked for me when I was trying to start varnish cache.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue that I solved doing:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
```

Comment: Thanks - this solved the issue for me. (I also needed to create the directory first):


sudo mkdir /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs

Answer (score 1):

Maybe /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk not found. You can try switch xcode to xcode application.
`sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

Comment: I tried but unfortunately this does not work. It gives me the same error

Comment: Try replace path in isysroot with `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk`

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I followed all the hints to update [R COMPILER TOOLS FOR RCPP ON MACOS](https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/).
Using MacOS X Catalina 10.15 and R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) -- "Action of the Toes" on Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit).

Not my own idea/knowledge but courtesy of https://superuser.com/a/1490988/918146

Answer (score 0):

I also had that problem for an iOS project. The project was building for iOS 13.5 (although I set the target to 13.0). Suddenly, everything was updated in the background to 13.6, and the compiler could not find the reference to the 13.5 SDK any longer. I inspected the folder where the SDK should have been (based on the error message), and I found

```
drwxrwxr-x  7 root  wheel  [...] iPhoneSimulator.sdk
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  [...] iPhoneSimulator13.6.sdk -> iPhoneSimulator.sdk
```

but no 13.5. Thus, following Thanh Vu I created the link

```
sudo ln -s iPhoneSimulator.sdk iPhoneSimulator13.5.sdk
```

That solved the problem. All simulators now run as 13.6.